# Extracting nodes from highways

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am using overpass turbo to extract nodes from highways(=motorway). Below is the code that I am using. However, this code gives me all the nodes in the bounding box and does not filter the highways.

```
[out:xml];
(
(way(39.90,32.83,39.96,32.89);)->.a;
((way.a["highway"="motorway"]);)->.b;
((way.a["highway"="motorway_link"]);)->.b;
);
(.b;>;);
out body qt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see my answer posted on help.osm.org: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/41754/extracting-node-from-highways

Answer (score 1):

Try this query instead:

```
[out:xml]
[timeout:25]
;
(
  way
    ["highway"="motorway"]
    (39.90,32.83,39.96,32.89);
  way
    ["highway"="motorway_link"]
    (39.90,32.83,39.96,32.89);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

You can [view it on overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/8ea). Note that it doesn't return any results because the given bounding box doesn't contain motorways. Either increase the bounding box size or choose a different highway value, for example *highway=primary*.